# How to open a Github pull request with live server vscode

Tags: visual-studio-code, pull-request

When someone makes a pull request on my repository (for a website), how do I open that pull request on vscode and view it on live server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When someone creates a pull request for your Github repository, the pull request has a URL with a unique ID (i.e. `1234`):

```
https://github.com/user/project/pull/1234
```

You can fetch the pull request to your local repository, and create a local branch for it (i.e. `pr-1234`), with this command where `1234` is the unique ID of the pull request:

```
git fetch origin pull/1234/head:pr-1234
```

Then switch to your local branch:

```
git checkout pr-1234
```

Now you can build the project and run it locally as you please.

When you're happy with it you can merge the pull request via the Github UI.